# I really shouldn't have the reputation I have, should I?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

In my infinite wisdom I answered two questions in the last 24 hours.

- [What's wrong with being spoon-fed aka just asking for a solution?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141550/whats-wrong-with-being-spoon-fed-aka-just-asking-for-a-solution/141553#141553)
- [Why was this question closed as not constructive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141625/why-was-this-question-closed-as-not-contructive/141633#141633)

Both questions have by now been deleted. What I expected to see is for my reputation to drop again by the 190 points I gained from them. But that didn't happen and as of yet still hasn't happened.

I [raised the issue in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1037825#1037825) today (with regards to the first question linked) and we came to the conclusion that it's most likely due to the deletion of the user's account and probably a temporary glitch.

I still assume that the system will correct this at some point. But I found it interesting enough to raise the issue and to see if anybody else is experiencing the same thing.

What might cause this problem? Is it a bug perhaps? Is this expected behavior? Or have I completely misunderstood something and should I still keep the reputation earned anyway?

Comment: Why is the second one different from the first? Both questions were auto-deleted because the user's account was deleted.

Comment: @animuson That second user's account was deleted? Okay, then it's the same. I did not know/expect that.

Comment: This bug most likely exists because the auto-deletions don't actually create a "delete" event in the revision history. The reputation recalculation majigger might just not be seeing them.

Comment: @animuson Yeah, I suspected as much. But my assumption that the second deletion was a regular deletion (not related to a user deletion) made me suspicious. Anyway, glad that's all cleared up. I would hate to seem to be too helpful. :)

Comment: @Bart: Regular deletions also take a couple of minutes/hours until they affect reputation.

Comment: I am lucky, I restricted myself to snarky comments in those threads, so I lost nothing. NOTHING, I SAY!!! Bwhahaha.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill That will teach me to be helpful. Snark it is. TURN ON THE SNARK!!

Comment: For justice, this Q should be upvoted to exactly +38 as compensation for your efforts in the past 24h.

Comment: @Mat Ha, [that's not why I asked the question](http://i.imgur.com/ZKyMP.jpg)...at all....

Comment: This question gave me an idea in the shower: an image imitating Lucky Charms except all the marshmallows are red X's and the text reads "they're automagically deleted." I decided that's way too much work though.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill and Bart, this is the Summer of Love, not the Summer of Snark. Please try to keep that in mind!

Comment: @animuson -- +1 for the lovely image of those magical unicorn shepherds, the noble leprechauns.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh suuure, we will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you gained 0 reputation today, 10 yesterday, and 40 on the 28th. Looks like those 190 reputation points are gone to me:

[image: Bart's reputation]

If you want to be certain, go visit https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation for a quick overview and the option to re-calculate.

Comment: Really? Hmm, I still see 40 today and 160 yesterday. Even with "show removed posts" enables I see no mention of the reputation being removed again. I'll try the link.

Comment: That's probably caching. Wait a few minutes.

Comment: Try a force-reload in your browser, or clear your cache.

Comment: Ha, that fixed my reputation (it's now down by the expected amount). I had already cleared my cache several times.

Comment: Yup, your reputation dropped down for me. :-)

Comment: @Bart: I also didn't lose my [60 rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141568) yet, but I'm in no hurry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Still have the following though: http://i.imgur.com/oV1ng.png But I assume that will correct itself soon enough. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dennis People got suspicious about my level of procrastination. Now I can claim again it's not that bad. ;)